# Display distinct text after user has selected a set of filters

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm currently using the following code to display a text with a Long Text Viewer when the user selects a Country from the slicer:

```
Notes = 
IF(
    HASONEFILTER(Data[Country]),
    CONCATENATEX(Data, Data[Comments], "\n\n"),
    "Please select only one Country from the list."
)
```

However, I've now separated [Comments] from the Data dataset into another dataset called Comment. I'm not sure how the relationships quite work but I checked the Manage Relationships dialog box and a 1:M relationship is active between the Data and Comment datasets.

This is how both datasets look like:

```
> Data dataset
Month | Year | Region | Prod % | ...
Jan   | 2016 | NAM    | 80%    | ...
Jan   | 2016 | LAM    | 40     | ...
Jan   | 2016 | EUR    | 60%    | ...
Jan   | 2016 | AFR    | 70%    | ...
Jan   | 2016 | SEA    | 80%    | ...
Jan   | 2016 | GCN    | 70%    | ...
```

```
> Comment dataset
Month | Year | Region | Comments
Jan   | 2016 | NAM    | Jan NAM comment here
Jan   | 2016 | LAM    | Jan LAM comment here
Jan   | 2016 | EUR    | Jan EUR comment here
Jan   | 2016 | AFR    | Jan AFR comment here
Jan   | 2016 | SEA    | Jan SEA comment here
Jan   | 2016 | GCN    | Jan GCN comment here
```

Is it possible that when the user selects a [Month], [Year] and [Region] from the Data dataset, it would display the appropriate [Comments] from the Comment dataset? Also, I'm not sure on how Primary Keys work in Power BI (both datasets don't have any Primary Keys).

Edit: So I tried this formula after merging the Comment dataset with the Data dataset:

```
Notes = 
IF(
    HASONEFILTER(Data[Region]) && HASONEFILTER(Data[Year]) && HASONEFILTER(Data[Month]),
    CONCATENATEX(Data, Data[Comment.Comment], "\n\n"),
    "Please select only one Period and Region from the list"
)
```

However, it is displaying the comment multiple times (there were 4 countries selected in the dataset. Would it be possible to make it display the [Comment] that is unique to that [Month], [Year] and [Region]?

Comment: The DAX should work fine. Can you explain more on `it is displaying the comment multiple times (there were 4 countries selected in the dataset).`? What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

I would add a VALUES function to your CONCATENATEX function to summarize the Comments, e.g.

CONCATENATEX( VALUES ( Data[Comment.Comment] ) , Data[Comment.Comment], "\n\n")